# In ShellExecute, how to specify print parameters like page range, tray etc?

Tags: python, windows

This is the code I'm using to print a pdf file on a Windows machine using Python. I've adobe Acrobat Reader installed to aid in printing.

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0,"print",file_path,"NPIAC1EC3 (HP LaserJet Pro MFP M226dw)",".",3)
```

How can I add additional options to mention things like Printer Tray/Page Source, page range etc?

I've read the documentation on [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) from MSDN .

I've seen in the documentation that there is a **lpParameters** (I'm totally guessing that this is where I specify printing parameters) but no explanations on how to use it with "print" parameter.

Comment: `How can I add additional options to mention things like Printer Tray/Page Source, page range etc?` What makes you think that is possible? _I am not saying it isn't, just curious._

Comment: The `print` verb that you pass to `ShellExecute()` takes everything as default. It is there to support a context menu option *print* such as you would see in Explorer. For that reason, it's not parameterizable.

Comment: Is there any way of print files by specifying printer tray and page limit through python( in windows) or through windows command

Comment: @Parvathy There is no easy way, or even a moderately difficult way, to do what you want. You would have to write a PDF renderer. I think that is a bigger project than you may want to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

The linked documentation states what what you want is not possible. Commented extracts (emphasize mine):

Syntax:

> ```
> HINSTANCE ShellExecute(
>   _In_opt_ HWND    hwnd,
>   _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpOperation,
>   _In_     LPCTSTR lpFile,
>   _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpParameters,
>   _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpDirectory,
>   _In_     INT     nShowCmd
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
> ...
>
> - lpOperation [in, optional]
>
>   Type: LPCTSTR
>
>   A pointer to a null-terminated string, referred to in this case as a verb, ... The following verbs are commonly used:
>   ...
>
>   print
>
>   Prints the file specified by lpFile. **If lpFile is not a document file, the function fails**.

So when you use `"print"` as a verb `lpFile` shall be a document file

> ...
>
> - lpParameters [in, optional]
>
>   Type: LPCTSTR
>
>   If lpFile specifies an executable file, this parameter is a pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the parameters to be passed to the application. The format of this string is determined by the verb that is to be invoked. **If lpFile specifies a document file, lpParameters should be NULL**.

So when you use `print` as the verb, `lpFile` must be a document file, and `lpParameters` must be null: there is no provision to pass additional parameters to a `ShellExecute` print action.

Comment: Is there any way of print files by specifying printer tray and page limit through python( in windows) or through windows command.

Comment: @Parvathy: Yes of course, but you will have to dig into the [Printing API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and manage to interface it from Python...