# printing specific pages form pdf file using print scope string

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I need to print selected pages of *.pdf file using excel VBA.
I need to do this not by providing scope "from - to" but giving scoope of pages like "1-3,4,8, 17-25"

I can only print whole file using below code:

````
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function PrintThisDoc(formname As Long, FileName As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim X As Long
X = ShellExecute(formname, "Print", FileName, 0&, 0&, 3)
End Function

Sub testPrint()
Dim printThis
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
strDir = "C:\Users\any\Desktop"
strFile = "somefile.pdf"


printThis = PrintThisDoc(0, strDir & "\" & strFile)
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Unfortunately no. I don't need to print sheets to pdf. I need to use excel VBA to print specific pages from existing pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50366592/8571717), it is not possible using `ShellExecute` alone. What you would need is to write a script which will open the file in whatever PDF reader you have installed, find a "Print" button there and provide all the options. This will take a huge amount of work and will depend on the version of Windows and the PDF reader, so basically it will work only for you, and not for other users.
If you want to go this path though, take a look at `FindWindow` and `SendMessage` WinAPI functions.